# iPhone: Catch the events when App running in background

Tags: iphone, event-handling, background, cllocationmanager, device-orientation

Can anyone please let me know if it is possible to handle events like OrientationChanged, Shake, LocationChanged etc.. when my App running in background?

I have tried following code but it gets invoked only when my app running in foreground!

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//if the time interval returned from core location is more than two minutes we ignore it because it might be from an old session
if ( abs([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate: [NSDate date]]) < 120) {     
    self.currentLocation = newLocation;
}
NSLog(@"lat: %f long:%f",currentLocation.coordinate.latitude,currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

You should include **location-services** in your info.plist file under the key **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities**

then your app will receive location updates in the background.
However this drains the battery at a faster rate..without user knowing much..If possible you should register for only **significant location**

orientation changed updates won't be possible in background.
shake might be..i am not sure